# Call AWS Insight query from AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to extract some data from CloudWatch Logs each day.

Today, i use use Insight to get only data i want to export.

I would like to automate this export.

It is possible to call an Insight function from Lamba ?

Or there is any solution to export filtered data from CloudWatch ?

(A Lambda function is already subscribed to the CloudWatch Stream and it is not possible for me to use this and it is impossible to add another subscription)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call CloudWatch Logs Insights with the SDK (methods with **query** in the name): https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/logs.html#CloudWatchLogs.Client.get_query_results

Comment: Thank's ! I can call the query with "start_query" and get result with "GetQueryResults"